# Can I bring (and return with) a shortwave radio receiver via Ataturk Airport?

Tags: airports, turkey, security

I would very much like to bring there a marvelous Tecsun PL-600, which is this piece of wonderful equipment:

https://swling.com/blog/2014/07/the-mega-shortwave-radio-review-of-the-pl-880-pl-660-ats-909x-and-icf-sw7600gr/

It also has Air band, which means you can listen to the ATC traffic.

Traditionally, shortwave radio has been (and is) used by countries for propaganda stuff, other than just normal programmes.

I hold a business visa (mechanic/assembly).
Will I run into trouble?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Local here.

I have mailed to the [airport support](https://www.istanbulsairport.com/en/contact-us) and they replied as;

> We would like to inform you that the information we have received **does
>   not constitute any problem in terms of security**, in particular, in the
>   interest of the request, we ask you to contact Atatürk Airport Customs
>   Directorate with the reason of customs procedures

I have also mailed to customs directorate but they didn't give any response to my mail.

I strongly suspect you *don't* run into any trobule for that device.

Comment: It's great that you are including where to address such questions, as I have a few more for upcoming trips. Tesekkurler!

Comment: If customs directorate response me, I will ping you as well.

Answer (score 4):

Just like Soner predicted I made it through both security checkpoints at IST, at the last of which I had the radio "inspected" (looked at skeptically, for the reason of not being either a laptop or a tablet I guess) and after some laughs all seemed OK with everyone. :)

For some reason, shortly after Soner Gönül's response, the IST airport site went first down and then into different phases of a *degraded* mode, so his link is sadly no longer available.

Here, just like in basically every country on Earth, showing an effort to learn the local language can lubricate any bureaucracy quite a bit.

Comment: Since Ataturk Airport was closed, I update the link of "Contact US" page for the new airport. Thanks.